# PHP OOP Uploading form entry

Tags: php, oop

IM trying to move away from procedural code and starting to get my feet wet with OOP, it is slow going but I am learning. I would like some help / opinion on the following:

Consider The Following View / HTML page which creates a simple form

[image]

An extract of the Class `CreateJob{}` I created looks like this:

```
function uploadJob($category, $headline, $description, $location){

        $sql ="INSERT INTO jobs (category, headline, description, location)
                        VALUES(:category, :headline, :description, :location)";
        $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmnt->bindValue(':category', $category);
        $stmnt->bindValue(':headline', $headline);
        $stmnt->bindValue(':description', $description);
        $stmnt->bindValue(':location', $location);
        $stmnt->execute();
        if($stmnt->rowCount() > 0){
            return $success = "Job Successfully Created";
        }
        else{
            return $error = 'SOMETHING WENT WRONG';
        }
    }
```

When the form is submitted the following is triggered via `isset()` and the object `$newJob` is created

```
if(isset($_POST['postJob'])){

         $obj = new CreateJob();

        $jobCategory = $_POST['jobCategory'];
        $jobDescription = $_POST['jobDescription'];
        $jobHeadline = $_POST['jobHeadline'];
        $jobLocation = $_POST['jobLocation'];

       $newJob = $obj->uploadJob($jobCategory, $jobDescription, $jobHeadline, $jobLocation);
      }
```

Everything works fine, however *this code feels to procedural for me*, and I feel I am missing some OOP concepts...?

Specifically is my method `uploadJob()` inside the `CreateJob{}` class correct or should I change some aspects of it?

Any other help / advice appreciate. Please keep in mind im a rookie!

EDIT:

Here is part of my table `jobs`, should anybody want to view it when attempting to answer the question

[image]

Comment: Spontaneously I'd say the class should implement a `Job` and be called like that. Methods on a `Job` object could be the well known CRUD actions: `create`, `read`, `update`, `delete`. So you can create a job from different sources and "work" with it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment please could you elaborate further if you dont mind! Thank you

Comment: Nothing more to elaborate here. Do you have a _specific_ question? Otherwise just follow the well known CRUD pattern.

Comment: If you don't have any references to `$this` in your code, then there's not much point in making it OOP. When you write OOP code, you should be putting data into object properties and then using it in the methods.

Comment: Don't just use OOP for its own sake, think about the purpose of organizing your code into classes and objects.

Comment: Combine both comments, mine and the one @Barmar made: you implement a `job` class that holds all information definition the job internally in properties. Then you can do with that job what your action parameters indicate.

Comment: @Barmar so am I correct to assume I should set `$category, $headline, $location, $description` as properties and then refer to them by using `$this`

Comment: Something like that. You could set them in the class constructor.

Comment: BTW, you have an undefined variable `$db`. That should probably also be a property.

Comment: @Barmar sorry that was a copy paste error from original code

Comment: it's question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

OOP is most about organization n classes on the system so it's hard to judgement about oop sinking about one class but here can be some improvement

Trying to use factory pattern to create new objects. In client code it can be looks like

```
 $obj = jobFactory::create(some params)
```

better pass values to uploadJob as array of parameters or even better some object that get $_POST array and convert it in proper object for uploadJob method

also you can use try catch for example 
//in controller

```
 try {
      $obj = jobFactory::create(some params);
   //but it's question why you need new object here?
      $obj->uploadJob($obj with post parameters)
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
```

and somewhere in uploadJob or jobFactory::create can trow error